# LVDS driver signals measurement

Tags: oscilloscope, differential, lvds

This is background: I have a self-made PCB, which is used to connect the camera via the CameraLink interface.
When I connected everything together, it turns out that the camera is signalling me via LED an error associated with the received command.... but I don't send anything yet.

I came to the conclusion that maybe if I send the correct command to it (which I am not 100% sure, I hope I have understood the documentation), it will be accepted by the camera and I will receive a confirmation. Unfortunately, the camera did not respond at all and every few seconds it shows the same error again and again. As if it hadn't noticed the command at all.

This is the problem:
Commands are transmitted via UART standard via LVDS DS90LV011A driver:
[image: LVDS driver]

With an oscilloscope I checked that the correct signal is coming from the control unit to pin 5. Therefore, I would like to check whether I have the correct signal at the differential output. How to correctly check such a signal with a simple oscilloscope with standard probes?

Comment: Something does not make sense. UART over LVDS?

Comment: It seems that UART is not a good name here. This is serial RS-644 communication.

Comment: So you are attempting to use an LVDS driver to generate RS-422 signals? UART is fine, it’s LVDS that is the problem.

Comment: The connection is like: 
1. FPGA output; single-ended signal; on my PCB.
2. LVDS driver; DS90LV011A; on my PCB. 
3. CameraLink cable; it connects my PCB with camera. 
4. LVDS receiver; DS90LV012A; in camera.
5. FPGA in camera.

Comment: Number 4 and 5 are in the camera housing, so I don't have access to them. All I know about camera status is that blinking LED.

Comment: What is the baud rate of that connection?

Comment: Transmission is simple: 8 data bits, no parity, 1 stop bit and baud rate = 9600 bps.

Comment: LVDS I.e., RS-644 makes absolutely no sense in such link. It’s way overkill.

Comment: This is in accordance with the CameraLink standard.